# Embeded Plots Missing when Knitting to PDF

Tags: r, pdf, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I know this question has been asked in different formats, but when searching I couldn't find a solution or problem similar to mine. 
Using Mac with RStudio (Version 1.0.153 ) R (version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30) -- "Kite-Eating Tree")

I am just trying to knit to a PDF (weave using knitr) in R markdown, but when I do, the plots are missing. When I knit to HTML the plots are there. I am using the earlywarnings package which helps create the plots. See example below using R markdown:

````
```{r, earlywarnings, fig.keep='all'}
library(earlywarnings)
data("foldbif")
x = foldbif
plot.ts(x)
```
````

That plot shows in the pdf output, but not when I create other plots like these:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE,results='hide',fig.keep='all', fig=TRUE}
out<-generic_ews(x,winsize=50,detrending="gaussian",
bandwidth=5,logtransform=FALSE,interpolate=FALSE)
```
````

or this one:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, results='hide', fig.keep='all', fig=TRUE, warning=FALSE}
qda = qda_ews(x, param = NULL, winsize = 50, detrending = "gaussian",
bandwidth = NULL, boots = 100,s_level = 0.05, cutoff = 0.05,
detection.threshold = 0.002, grid.size = 50, logtransform = FALSE, interpolate = FALSE)
```
````

The last function also only displays 2 out of 3 plots, but I'll figure that out another time.

Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if this was not clear.

Comment: I believe this is because you are assigning the plot to a variable as opposed to just calling it.  Try removing the `out <- ` from your second chunk.

Comment: Yeah I've messed around with that previously and it just changes the presence/absence of the dataframe data which I don't need.

Comment: The issue might be that the developers used `dev.new()` within their function.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the issue is related with the use of `dev.new()`. I copy-pasted the code of the function, removed it (the one line 136 of the function) and it worked, i.e. I get the figure on my pdf. There may be a way to call a function to avoid the effect of `dev.new()` that I am not aware of.

Comment: Oh that makes sense! Did you remove it using the `trace()` or source it in after editing?

Comment: I used `generic_ews` without bracket to have a look at the code, then I used `capture.output(generic_ews)` to copy/paste the code of the function and edit it myself in a separate file that I sourced (`source()`) afterwards. Hope this helps!